# How to restrict the numberfield input from entering more than two decimals

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

> It seems very easy to force the decimal to some precision and their are many ways.I have tried using all as:

**1st way : Using config**

```
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Balance',
            name: 'balancefield',    
            decimalPrecision:2
```

**Alternative : by overrriding or extending as shown  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287584/how-do-i-force-the-display-of-a-decimal-in-an-extjs-numberfield-to-a-certain-pre)**

**Or using regular expressions**

> All of these work on blur or some other event or function.Is their a way to stop the input after two decimals. In **textfields** we can use **RegEx** and **maskRe** configs.But in numberfield,is their anything like maskRe,so that user cannot enter the more than two decimals.
>   Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `maskRe` is indeed used internally by the number field, so you'll have to mimick its behaviour. That is, listening the `keypress` event of the field, and stop the event if the input does fits you.

Example, for enforcing two digits decimal precision using a regex:

```
Ext.widget('numberfield', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,enableKeyEvents: true
    ,listeners: {
        keypress: function(field, e) {
            var v = field.getValue();
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(v)) {
                if (/\.\d{2,}/.test(v)) {
                    e.stopEvent();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thnks rixo. I actually tried this before,but missed **e.stopEvent();**

Comment: just having an issue.Is their anything to restrict the digits before decimal to 15.I have tried with different regex in above solution you have provided with.Can you please help me with this.Thnks again

Comment: The above solution is having some issue
> I am able to enter three 0's followed by any no. of digits after decimal.